# How to know a location ( like : (CLLocation *)newLocation)) whether on the road?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, mapkit, cllocation

I was doing a map ios app using `CLLocation` and I was wondering whether there is an API for judging whether a point on the map is on the road, but not in an appartment or in anywhere in-side the house?

I have seen there are certain navigation application who can keep the points on the road.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/route-me/route-me

Have a look there are so many example in this code you will an google api which provides us the route path latitude and longitutude and we draw a over lay on the map.

Hope this will help you.